# Its possible Call Unity 3D API from C# project and run on windows form like OpenTK?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, window

i am new in Unity 3D, i write code in c# and until now i use OpenTK for 3d rendering, now i would try use Unity 3d but it seems that this is not possible because Unity 3d not have API for windows form call is true? how i can call Unity function like OpenTk and draw my graphics on windows form ?

Comment: I think you still can use Unity API - UnityEngine.dll within your OpenTK or other OGL wrappers. The thing is you cannot use Unity's internal stuff to render picture to the screen buffer. Only things you can do is using some features/objects like `Vector3` etc.

Comment: Sorry , maybe i dont explain corrently, i am italian and not good english writer. I would like to use Unity 3D instead OpenTK because i seems to me that Unity 3D is more powerful ..i am wrong ?

Comment: If you really want to feel the power try native OpenGL with C/C++ but since you've asked about that. Yes it is more ... easy solution than using OpenTK but you cannot use it's drawing features and `GameObject` and all internal related stuff outside Unity Engine.

Comment: thank you very much for your, answer, it'a shame, so much power and i cannot use it from .net c# windows app, now you know any alternative or its better for me stay on Open Tk.

Comment: I must only draw 3D object profile with 3d shape , rotate , zoom and move it...

Comment: You can use Unity as a subprocess and specify parent widow handle to run inside your C# application but then you have to make some message pump from your application to the unity subprocess. For that you can [read this question](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-integrate-unity3d-into-c-wpf-application.332276/)